# com.sun.identity.authentication.spi.AuthLoginException(1):Error occurred while processing XML request

Tags: openssl, openam

I am doing login to openam server using following code:

```
        AuthContext lc = new AuthContext("/","https://server.ensarm.com:8443/openam/namingservice");
        AuthContext.IndexType indexType = AuthContext.IndexType.MODULE_INSTANCE;
        lc.login(indexType, "DataStore");
```

but getting this exception at lc.login(indexType, "DataStore"):

```
com.sun.identity.authentication.spi.AuthLoginException(1):Error occurred while processing XML request.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException(2):null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.AuthContext.processRequest(AuthContext.java:2000)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.AuthContext.runRemoteLogin(AuthContext.java:999)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.AuthContext.runLogin(AuthContext.java:764)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.AuthContext.login(AuthContext.java:655)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.AuthContext.login(AuthContext.java:598)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.AuthContext.login(AuthContext.java:401)
    at com.ensarm.openam.server.GreetingServiceImpl.getAuthContext(GreetingServiceImpl.java:107)
    at com.ensarm.openam.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(GreetingServiceImpl.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.identity.protocol.https.Https.init(Https.java:63)
    at com.sun.identity.protocol.https.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:65)
    ... 39 more
```

I have amconfig.properties file in my application also in system variable. But didn't understand what is missing there .

Comment: Does indexType have the value null when you are passing it in?

Comment: its not null when I am passing it. indextype value is module_instance. But I dont know about what the other parameter "Datastore" is..